# Implications of cointegration in logs versus cointegration in levels

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Suppose I have two random processes $X_t$ and $Y_t$, which are both $I(1)$ in levels and logs, ie, $\text{log}(X_t), \text{log}(Y_t)$ are $I(1)$ as well.

Suppose the variables are not cointegrated in levels but they are in logs, ie there does not exist $\mathbf{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $X_t - \beta Y_t$ is an $I(0)$ process, but $\exists! \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\text{log}(X_t) - \gamma \text{log}(Y_t)$ is a stationary process.

I have trouble understanding the implications of this. Naming $u_t = \text{log}(X_t) - \gamma \text{log}(Y_t)$ and rewriting this yields
\begin{equation}
\frac{X_t}{Y_t^\gamma} = e^{u_t}.
\end{equation}

Does this imply some kind of constant long term growth rate for the processes? My thinking is as follows: If we have $\text{E}(u_t) = 0$, we obtain $\frac{X_t}{Y_t^\gamma} = 1$ in the long run. Here $\gamma < 1$ implies that $X_t$ will grow faster (decrease slower) than $Y_t$, $\gamma > 1$ implying the opposite. For $\gamma = 1$ we seem to have have our cointegration in levels with cointegration vector $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\end{pmatrix}'$.

Is the thinking above correct here? Can we correctly conclude here that cointegration in levels should imply cointegration in logs (with addition of a constant), but not the other way around, as in the long run we have

$\begin{equation}
X_t - \beta Y_t = 0 \iff \frac{X_t}{Y_t} = \beta \iff \text{log}(X_t) - \text{log}(Y_t) - \text{log}(\beta) = 0.
\end{equation}$

Can such a conclusion be made about the long run relationships? And is there a text that covers this more in depth?